# VS 2015 Community - No property pages for C++ project

Tags: visual-studio

Every C++ project that I open with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition shows the following when trying to open project properties:

[image]

I've tried fully reinstalling (deleting folders in documents, appdata and program files) and repairing. I've reset all the settings, tried signing out and signing in with my Microsoft account, but none of it makes a difference. It doesn't occur for any other type of project (C#/Python/etc). Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: @Ramhound I expect it to show all of the build and linker setting panels. http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/images/vc10_include.gif